# Market / Customer Segmentation - Merging two different segmentations

Tags: r, clustering, k-means, unsupervised-learning, marketing

I have a database where each observation is a person. They were questioned on their attitude towards the consumption of X category of product. I have being using K-means to segment this data.

I have noticed that people under 19 years old tend to be quite different in their responses to those over 19.  I was thinking of dividing the data in `<19` and `>=19` and producing two clusterings and then merging them so as to produce a single report.

Does this make any sense from a data mining point-of-view? Is there precedent for doing so?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the clustering algorithm correctly, it should already discover something like this. Other than that, it sounds more like *decision trees* to me than clustering!
**Maybe you'll want to build a decision tree with early pruning, and then use the leaves as "clusters"?**

As your data probably is *discrete*, k-means will have a systematic error. K-means is best for *truly continuous* vector data, where each dimension should have the same value range and semantic scale.

Definitely pay attention to your cluster sizes. If you are seeing empty or near-empty clusters, your data is not working for k-means!

Comment: Why K-means will have a systematic error for discrete data?

Comment: Because the means aren't discrete anymore. You may want to look at k-modes and similar variants of k-means.